# How to Add Object to Array State in ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rxjs

I have this array of objects state, and it is working fine.
I need add another object to it dynamically.

```
const [productData, SetProductData] = useState({
    sizes: [
        {id: 2, value: 'Small', isActive: false},
        {id: 2, value: 'Medium', isActive: false},
        {id: 2, value: 'Large', isActive: true},
        {id: 2, value: 'X Large', isActive: false},
        {id: 2, value: 'XX Large', isActive: false}
    ]
})
```

I tried to do it like this, but it is not working

```
const addObjectToArray = obj => {
    SetProductData(current => [...current, obj]);
};

addObjectToArray( {id: 3, value: 'XXX Large', isActive: true} )
```

I also need to update it dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep the same structure in your state. You had an object, and you're changing it to an array. So

```
const addObjectToArray = obj => {
  SetProductData(current => ({
    ...current,
    sizes: [...current.sizes, obj]
  }));
};

addObjectToArray( {id: 3, value: 'XXX Large', isActive: true} )
```

Comment: You're welcome.  You can flag the answer as correct :)